# I am making a wcf service application how do I get the full path of a xml file?

Tags: c#, xml, wcf

I am making a wcf service application how do I get the full path of a xml file? The file is on a visual studio project folder, is going to move to another computer and the path will be change.

Answer (score 0):

```
Server.MapPath("/PathToYourFiles");
```

More info here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpserverutility.mappath(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: I have add: using System.Web;
using System.Web.dll;  and I get an error with web.dll and the  Server.MapPath(file.xml); I there another library I need to include thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I removed using System.Web.dll;
and add the following:

string path = System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.MapPath("/fileName.xml");